# How to implement (sort, pagination) for Angular Material table which retrieves data through Rest API (JSON)?

Tags: json, sorting, rxjs, angular-material, mat-tab

I have this Material table that displays data from a JSON url through Rest API. I now want to use sort\pagination on the material table but can't get through it. Below are the screenshots. How do I refer `MatTableDataSource` and `UserDataSource` both together ? I want to stick to using `Observable`. Please advise, I am new to Angular.

Component.ts

```
    @Component({
  selector: 'app-tablefilter', 
  templateUrl: './tablefilter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tablefilter.component.scss']
})
export class TablefilterComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort; 

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name','email','phone','website', 'address']; 
  dataSource = new UserDataSource(this.dataService );

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}



  ngOnInit() {
  }

}

export class UserDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
    super();
  }
  connect(): Observable<Contacts[]> {
    return this.dataService.fetchPosts();
  }
  disconnect() {}
}
```

HTML

```
    <table mat-table matSort  class="mat-elevation-z8" [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="phone">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> phone
             </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let contacts">{{contacts.phone}}  </td>
      </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let contacts"> {{contacts.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> email </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let contacts"> {{contacts.email}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="website">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> website </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let contacts"> {{contacts.website}} </td>
      </ng-container>


      <ng-container matColumnDef="address">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> address </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let contacts"> {{contacts.address.street}} </td>
      </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
```

Service -data.service.ts

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import{ Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Contacts} from '../models/contacts.model';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

   private serviceUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';

  constructor( private http: HttpClient ) { }


  fetchPosts(): Observable<Contacts[]> {
    return this.http.get<Contacts[]>(this.serviceUrl )


  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MatTableDataSource` is a data source that accepts a client-side data array and includes native support of filtering, sorting (using `MatSort`), and pagination (using `MatPaginator`). Class `MatTableDataSource` extends the abstract class `DataSource`, hence there's no need to provide custom implementation as you intend to do with `UserDataSource`.

Therefore, get rid of `UserDataSource` and rewrite your `TablefilterComponent` as follows.

```
export class TablefilterComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['phone', 'name', 'email', 'website', 'address']; 
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Contact>; 

  @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true}) paginator: MatPaginator;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.fetchPosts().subscribe(contacts => {
       this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(contacts);
       this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
       this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    });
  }
}
```

Please have a look at the following [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s8wst7?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-sorting-example.ts)

Comment: Hi, Thanks, it has worked. Being new to all these, I have to ask , why did you replace contacts.model.ts with contact.type.ts? How is type.ts is different from model.ts ?

Comment: @Sz2013: There was no code for `contacts.model.ts` and I had to invent it for my StackBlitz. The name of the file doesn't matter, it's a question of taste (I use `.type.ts` for files that contain an `interface`).

Comment: just noticed I didn't add the contact.model.ts file to the screenshots. Thanks a lot for the explanations.